# Pidgin sound event when a message is received when the conversation window doesn't have focus

Tags: pidgin, audio

I'm looking for a way to set the sound preferences in Pidgin such that a sound is played only when a message is received when the conversation window doesn't have focus. There doesn't seem to be an option for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In Pidgin 2.5.7 Tools->Preferences->Sounds
I was able to unclick "Sounds when conversation has focus".  Then I have "message sent" clicked.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: yeah, I think that should work... just click "message received" with "sounds when conversation has focus" unchecked

Comment: yes that works, but only if the particular contact's chat window is already open on your computer. if he/she sends you a new message it pops up but no sound is played regardless of the above setting :(

Answer (score 0):

The magic is the "Message received begins conversation" sound event.  This should be checked.

I have the following boxes checked on the Sounds tab on the Preferences window:

- Sounds when conversation has focus
- Messages Received
- Message received begins conversation
- Attention received.

I also have Enable sounds set to Always.